# Simple logout component throws "Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component"

Tags: reactjs

This little `Logout.jsx` component logs-out the user...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { userLogout } from '../redux/actions/authActions';

const Logout = ({ to = '/loginForm' }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(userLogout());
  return <Redirect to={to} />;
};

export default Logout;
```

and is used in path `/logout` thus:

```
<Switch>
   ...      
  <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
```

In the console it gives the dreaded (and [apparently serious](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178#issuecomment-592662192)) message:

> Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different
>   component

Can someone spot why, and how to fix it?

Using react 16.13.0

Comment: where do you call this `<Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a logical mistake causing this error to pop up from another component (than `Logout`), try logging out once:

```
const Logout = ({ to = '/loginForm' }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userLogout());
  }, [dispatch]);
  return <Redirect to={to} />;
};
```

You don't want to `dispatch` (or logout) on every component render